# Sonatype nexus - what does published mean

Tags: nexus, sonatype

In my internal Sonatype Nexus, on the routing tab of a repository (Codehaus Snapshots for example) is says

```
--- Publishing ---
|   Status: Not published
|   Message: Discovery in progress or unable to discover remote content (see discovery status).
```

I am able to Browse Remote, but unable to Browse Index.

What *exactly* is meant by the term "published"?

Is this repo not available to my maven clients? They use `<mirrorOf>*` and get all artifacts from Nexus.

This seems a brain dead question. I've looked here, and in the Sonatype book, online sonatype documentation, and scraped Google, to no avail.

Answer (score 4):

This message means that the proxy's remote does not publish routing information, and that Nexus either wasn't able to crawl the remote's HTML directory listing, or is still in the process of doing so.

Have a look here for a description of how the routing feature works in Nexus:

https://support.sonatype.com/entries/30645946-How-does-Automatic-Routing-work-

Regarding search indexes, not all sites publish them.  They are entirely optional, a lack of a search index will not impact artifact downloads through the proxy.

To see if the remote publishes search indexes add this path to the remote's URL and see if it can be downloaded:

```
.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.properties
```